# SetInfo to a user in active directory error handling

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

I cant get the error handling to work in my VBScript to set details for a user.

I know why I cant set it because they have more access then me :) but i'm doing a 'bulk' update of user accounts and a few support accounts get flagged in my list.

but I want my script to continue if a usr account is found that has more access then me.

```
  Call GetusersDN(getDN) ' connecting to my domain and gets user details.


  Set myUser = GetObject ("LDAP://" & getDN)

  WScript.Echo "working on: " myUser.displayname

  NewDate = "06/30/2014"
  myUser.AccountExpirationDate = NewDate
  myUser.SetInfo
```

in the CMD window i get this error: "Active Directory: General access denied error"

So started Googling found this site http://www.selfadsi.org/errorcodes.htm

so tried adding the below code but still 'konks out' and stops.

```
  If (Err.number <> 0) Then 

   WScript.Echo Err.Description 
   WScript.Echo Err.Number
   WScript.Echo "Error: Attribute could not be written" 
   Wscript.Quit

  End If
```

that didnt work so I tried this

```
If Err.Description = "Active Directory: General access denied error" Then
  WScript.Echo Err.Number
End If
```

Comment: If you want to see errors you have to turn off VBS error handling. The program stops on errors so your error handling doesn't run. So start your program with ON ERROR RESUME NEXT. Now your code will execute and print err.number.

Comment: Andyou have to err.clear after handling it.